Как сделать так, чтобы inline кнопка вызывала reply кнопку?
В общем сейчас мне нужно реализовать то, чтобы когда нажимаешь на inline клавишу, вызывалась reply клавиатура.
Вот кусочек кода из user_commands:
from aiogram import types, Router, F, Dispatcher, Bot
from aiogram.filters import Command
import text
from keyboards import inline
from aiogram.types import Message
from config_reader import config

bot = Bot(config.bot_token.get_secret_value())
router = Router()
dp = Dispatcher()

@router.message(Command("start"))
async def salam(message: types.Message):


    file_path = './assets/ja.png'
    await message.answer_photo(
        photo=types.FSInputFile(
            path=file_path)
    )
    await message.answer(text.salam, reply_markup=inline.main_kb)

